# Using a Navigation bar and iMessage App

Tags: ios, autolayout, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller, imessage

I'm creating an iMessage App using a UISearchBar/UISearchController and a MKMapView. The search bar appears perfectly in compact view (I know you can't have search bars in compact view, but just for testing) pinned to the top of the screen. However, in expanded view the search bar is hidden by the iMessage navigation bar. I can't constrain the search bar to the top layout guide because the navigation controller is above the top layout guide. Any ideas on how to constrain the search bar below the iMessage top navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
I haven't been on top of iOS10 and didn't know about iMessage apps. Your question makes more sense now. I'll leave my original answer down here anyways.

---

This is a project that has the ***basics*** of the original iMessages app from apple. Of course there is still ***a lot more*** to tweak, but it should get you started.

Shows a table view with messages, the searchbar is originally hidden unless you scroll up to find it and once you click on the search bar the navigation bar hides and the search bar also shows the cancel button.

If you want to download the whole project so you can see how I set up the storyboard you can download the project here.
http://www.filedropper.com/forjeremykelleher

[image]
[image]

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var messages = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for x in 0...25 {
        messages.append(x)
    }

    // Start with the tableview scrolled down by 44
    // so the search bar doesn't show up only until you scroll back up
    // Like in the iMessage App.
    let height = tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size.height
    let pointXY = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height!)
    tableView.setContentOffset(pointXY, animated: false)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.messageLabel.text = "Message # \(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}

}

extension TableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Hide the navigation bar when they press on search
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

}

}
```

Comment: I believe the original question is about the new iMessage apps in iOS 10, not the default Messages app.

Comment: The question makes a lot more sense now.